How to render HTML content using the Interactivity API?
I'm testing the new Interactivity API and want build a block that renders the title and content of a random post.
This is the content of the render.php file:
<?php 
    $block_attributes = get_block_wrapper_attributes()
?>
<div
    <?php echo $block_attributes; ?>
    data-wp-interactive="mystore"
    <?php echo wp_interactivity_data_wp_context( array( 'isOpen' => false ) ); ?>
>
    <button data-wp-on--click="actions.getRandomPost">Show me a random post</button>

    <p data-wp-bind--hidden="!context.isOpen">
        <span data-wp-text="context.randomPost.title.rendered"></span>
        <div data-wp-text="context.randomPost.content.rendered"></div>
    </p>
</div>

This is the content of the view.js file:
import { store, getContext } from '@wordpress/interactivity'

store( 'mystore', {
    actions: {
        *getRandomPost() { // a generator function
            const context = getContext()
            context.isOpen = ! context.isOpen
            if ( context.isOpen ) {
                const posts = yield fetch(
                    'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
                ).then( function( response ){
                    return response.json()
                } )
                context.randomPost = posts[ ( Math.floor( Math.random() * posts.length ) ) ]
            }
        },
    }
} )

The issue is that the post content (context.randomPost.content.rendered) is displayed as raw HTML, without being properly interpreted as formatted HTML.
Example:
<p>Hello world! Welcome to <strong>WordPress</strong>. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>

Is there a way to display HTML content using the wp-text directive? Is there a specific directive to render HTML content?

This is the modified code that works for me based on Jacob Peattie's answer:
render.php file:
<?php 
    $block_attributes = get_block_wrapper_attributes()
?>
<div
    <?php echo $block_attributes; ?>
    data-wp-interactive="mystore"
    <?php
    echo wp_interactivity_data_wp_context(
        array(
            'isOpen'     => false,
            'randomPost' => null,
        )
    );
    ?>
>
    <button data-wp-on--click="actions.getRandomPost">Show me a random post</button>

    <p data-wp-bind--hidden="!context.isOpen">
        <span data-wp-text="context.randomPost.title.rendered"></span>
        <div data-wp-watch="callbacks.renderContent"></div>
    </p>
</div>

view.js file:
import { store, getContext, getElement } from '@wordpress/interactivity'

store( 'mystore', {
    callbacks: {
        renderContent() {
            const context = getContext();
            const element = getElement();
            if (context.randomPost !== null) {
                element.ref.innerHTML = context.randomPost.content.rendered;
            }
        },
    },
    actions: {
        *getRandomPost() { // a generator function
            const context = getContext()
            context.isOpen = ! context.isOpen
            if ( context.isOpen ) {
                const posts = yield fetch(
                    'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
                ).then( function( response ){
                    return response.json()
                } )
                context.randomPost = posts[ ( Math.floor( Math.random() * posts.length ) ) ]
            }
        },
    }
} )


Rather than binding text with a directive, you could bind a callback with data-wp-watch that sets the inner HTML of the div when it runs:
<div data-wp-watch="callbacks.renderContent"></div>

callbacks: {
    renderContent() {
        const context = getContext();
        const element = getElement();

        element.ref.innerHTML = context.randomPost.content.rendered;
    },
},

Since the callback uses context.randomPost.content.rendered, it should run any time that value changes.

I added your code and now I get an Uncaught TypeError: t.randomPost is undefined error

My code is only an example of the method. You need to make sure the variable name is correct and that it's set.

Exactly, this is the correct way to do it as of today!
But just so you know, a data-wp-dangerous-html component is in the roadmap: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/discussions/52904
